# How to iterate through every QSpinBox in QGridLayout

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I have the following problem. I'm using Qt in the newest version 5.2 and in my code I have 11`QSpinBox`. Every in `QGridLayout`. I want to iterate through every `QSpinBox` in this layout and set value that I read from file. When I'm using:

```
ui.QSpinBox->setValue()
```

is everything ok, but the code looks too long. 
I tried using:

```
static_cast<QSpinBox*>(ui.gridLayout->itemAtPosition(1,1)->widget())->setValue(100);
```

but I get exception Access violation and MS VS2010 show me this function in qatomic_mscv.h:

```
inline bool QAtomicOpsBySize<4>::deref(long &_q_value) Q_DECL_NOTHROW
{
    return QT_INTERLOCKED_DECREMENT(&_q_value) != 0;
}
```

So i thought about not using pointer to `QSpinBox` but an object:

```
static_cast<QSpinBox>(ui.gridLayout->itemAtPosition(1,1)->widget()).setValue(100);
```

but it didn't change the value. Any exception didn't occur.

OK, I used even dynamic_cast with pointer type and I got again access Violation but this time VS2010

point me to qscopedpointer.h:

```
inline T *data() const
    {
        return d;
    }
```

It happens for `qobject_cast` too.

I'm sure that position point to QSpinBox. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [qFindChildren](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) instead:

```
QList<QSpinBox*> spinBoxen = ui.findChildren<QSpinBox*>();
Q_FOREACH(QSpinBox *spinBox, spinBoxen) {
    // do something to do the spinBox
}
```